# What is a Donut Phrase™?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle, word-property

Bwahaha! You're not the only one who can make these puzzles, JLee!

(this is an unofficial continuation of JLee's [in]famous [Word/Phrase puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ajlee%20is%3Aquestion%20title%3Aphrase))

The following phrases of varying lengths follow a certain rule, or they do not. If one follows the rule, I call it a Donut Phrase™! If not, I suppose you could call it something else. See if you can find out the link between all the Donut Phrases™.

**Donut Phrases™**:

"Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight?"

"Four score and seven years ago..."

"We need a bigger boat."

"I'm not left-handed either."

"Please sir, can I have some more?"

"I'm gonna make him an offer he can't refuse."

"Avengers, assemble!"

"Punch the keys for god's sake!"

"If I say it's safe to surf this beach, it's safe to surf this beach!"

"This could be the beginning of a beautiful friendship."

"Yes I said yes I mean yes!"

"KHAN!"

"War. War never changes."

"As the suns fade, so dies humanity's hope."

"nope."

"You can't handle the truth!"

"Don't tease the octopus, kids!"

---

**But here are some phrases that are NOT Donut Phrases™...**

"Can't stop me now"

"I have a bad feeling about this."

"I am not left handed."

"You're the man now, dog"

"Captain Jean-luc Picard"

"just kept talking in one long incredibly unbroken sentence moving from topic to topic so that no one had a chance to interrupt it was really quite hypnotic"

"I love the smell of napalm in the morning."

"I must not fear. Fear is the mind killer. Fear is the little death, that brings total obliteration. I will face my fear. I will permit it to pass over me and through me, and when it has gone past I will turn the inner eye to see its path. Where the fear has gone, there will be nothing. Only I will remain."

"Not sure if puzzle, or just collection of memes."

"No."

"I will leave you as you left me, Kirk. Alone, at the center of a dead planet. Buried alive."

"Yup."

"I am the very model of a modern major general, I've information animal, vegetable, and mineral, I know the kings of England and all the fights historical, from Marathon to Waterloo in order categorical"

"I want the truth."

"You spoony bard!"

"I'm a Barbie girl, in a Barbie world."

"Bonjour, comment tu t'appelles?"

Hint:

> I used a program from the code golf stack exchange site (which is here: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) to quickly verify these phrases, but in order to do so, I had to make a few modifications to the phrases. (If you're on the right track, those modifications will seem very obvious)

Hint 2 (this is a big one):

> Each phrase's status is determined by its relationship to a single letter.

Final Hint: (seriously this gives away quite a bit)

> The letter you're looking for is different for each phrase. And if you compare the shorter phrases, you might not even need a calculator.

Even more Finaler hint:

> When finding "the donut hole," you need to round off to the nearest letter.

Here's a picture to make side by side comparisons easier:
[image: Donut Phrases™]

Comment: Can you make a table like JLee to compare easily?

Comment: His puzzles use a picture file. When I get home I'll try to whip one up, but for now the text will have to do. Sorry for the inconvenience. Also, some of the phrases are larger than normal. For now, at least, you can easily copy and paste them, which is something.

Comment: You didn't trademark "Donut Phrase".  JLee's gonna trademark it and have your question closed as a duplicate!

Comment: Curses! Foiled again!

Comment: If they don't follow the rules, can we call them "Do-not phrases"?

Comment: I like your style friend. You must like horrible puns as much as I do.

Comment: There's only one donut-related question on PPCG: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53549/holy-hole-in-a-donut-batman Not sure how it relates to the phrases.

Comment: It doesn't actually. Sorry for that incidental red herring. You'll have to try harder.

Comment: Cool. I hope I can solve it, but I'm usually better at making puzzles than solving them.

Comment: Is punctuation important in finding the property of the phrase? Or could it be ignored?

Comment: Is hank a donut phrase?  IF you give this kind of hint

Comment: Are the inaccuracies in the quotes relevant to whether the phrase is a Donut Phrase or not?

Comment: Q: "What is a donut phrase?" A: "Delicious."

Comment: Punctuation is not important, and neither is capitalization. Those were the modifications I made when checking the phrases. That, and I had to delete the spaces.

Comment: The last line of Casablanca is "Louie, I think this is the beginning of a beautiful friendship".

Comment: Well my memory sucks but the quotes as they're posted are still correct by the algorithm. If it bothers you enough, I can check the "real" phrases later to see how they hold up.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this has something to do with YTMND. I can find links to it in the phrases 'You're the man now, dog', 'KHAN!' and 'Punch the keys for gods sake!'. Still looking for more.

Comment: I'm a fan of some of the old ytmnd's and those are references, but the key to the phrase isn't connected to that. It's tagged calculation-puzzle, if that helps.

Comment: this is driving me crazy! aaaaaaaaahhhhhhhh

Comment: hehehe! I can't help but feel Schadenfreude , as annoying as some of your puzzles are. But here's a hint: Each phrase is determined by its relationship to a single letter.

Comment: You said that punctuation and capitalisation are not important, and that you had to delete spaces to check the phrase. Can you confirm that the implication of that is, if all spaces and punctuation were removed and the word made entirely lowercase, its status as a donut phrase would be unchanged?

Comment: absolutely correct. The status of donut phrase is based completely on the letters, not any of the other characters.

Comment: I'm stumped... every time I think I am on to something it leads me nowhere. I'm losing so much time on this!

Comment: How about another hint?  To which specific letter are you referring in Hint 2?

Comment: Oh I suppose I can give one final hint.

Comment: In case it's unclear, when I say that the letter is different for each phrase, I mean that they are independent - it's not the same for each one, and the phrase determines the letter.

Comment: There are lot's of phrases on Donut Phrases related to NON-Donut phrases. I think there is a connection for each of them. For example: "I want the truth" - "You can't handle the truth" ; "I'm not left handed" - "I'm not left-handed either" and so on. Also googling phrases gives some results, for example ["Four score and seven years ago"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/four_score_and_seven_years_ago) is related to Abraham Lincoln (letters are A,L?). Am I on the right track?

Comment: Not quite. When I created the criteria for what made a phrase a donut phrase I went and thought up a bunch of phrases and then checked them, adding them to either one list or another. You're right that some are connected, but that's because I thought it was cool that there were related phrases from movies, games, books, etc. that would make for an interesting puzzle. Try and think of ways that you could generate a single letter from a phrase, and go from there.

Comment: This puzzle seems like it would take a long time for people to verify each hypothesis, since it seems to require a lot of calculation (with a calculator).  This might explain the lack of answers.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if someone posted a hypothesis, showed that it worked with the smallest of the phrases, and then went one by one to check the others. The answer is surprisingly simple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I only checked a few, so I'm not sure, but I think it's

> A donut phrase is one where the "average letter" is not found in the phrase. Here average letter is found by converting all letters into numbers where a=1 b=2 etc. and averaging. Round the average and convert back to a letter to get the average letter. It is called a donut phrase since the average letter is the hole, and the letters around it make up the donut.

Comment: I can confirm that it works for "Have you ever danced with the devil in the pale moonlight?"  (average = K) and "Yes I said yes I mean yes!" (average = O).

Comment: Congratulations! You are victorious! I have been waiting so long for someone to figure this out.

Comment: Here's the code golf challenge where I found the program. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53675/calculate-average-characters-of-string  And here's one of many ways to check it: http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=Uq%7Bi%2B_U)%3AUd%2Fmoco%7D%2F%3B&input=StackExchange DO NOTE that you have to make all the characters either uppercase or lowercase and remove all punctuation and spacing.

Comment: I was waiting for that last hint. I was stuck looking at mod 26 as the donut until I saw the part on rounding.

Comment: When I first created the puzzle I was bouncing back and forth on the idea of whether "donut" was an appropriate term, and tried to think of other things that might be closer, but then I remembered back in grade school, when we learned about mean, median, and mode, only the mean could be a number missing from the series.

Comment: As a side note: it's a lot easier to make something that's not a donut phrase because the longer the sentence gets, the more likely it is to include the donut hole. A lot of sentences ended up with J or something around it as the donut hole, though, and since that's actually a very rare letter, I was able to find quite a few.